# How to copy a distinct subset of collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a source collection in MongoDB with the following documents indexed on the first 4 fields.

```
[{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10000', store: '1234', item: '1234', size: 'L'}, 
{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10000', store: '1234', item: '1234', size: 'L'}, 
{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10100', store: '1234', item: '1234', size: 'L'}, 
{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10100', store: '1234', item: '1234', size: 'L'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08800', store: '2345', item: '2345', size: 'M'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08800', store: '2345', item: '2345', size: 'M'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08810', store: '2345', item: '2345', size: 'M'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08810', store: '2345', item: '2345', size: 'M'}]
```

I'd like to copy the distinct documents from my source collection (based on the first 4 fields) over to another collection. The new collection should have the documents below. My source collection is huge and so performance will be an important consideration on how to effect this move.

```
[{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10000', store: '1234', item: '1234', size: 'L'}, 
{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10100', store: '1234', item: '1234', size: 'L'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08800', store: '2345', item: '2345', size: 'M'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08810', store: '2345', item: '2345', size: 'M'}]
```

I tried the aggregate pipeline but could only get to listing the distinct values for the documents but not the entire document.

```
[{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10000', store: '1234'}, 
{state: 'NY', city: 'New York', zip: '10100', store: '1234'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08800', store: '2345'}, 
{state: 'NJ', city: 'Newark', zip: '08810', store: '2345'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$first` with Root to get the first (or last) document in the grouping criteria:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        state: "$state",
        city: "$city",
        zip: "$zip",
        store: "$store"
      },
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$doc" },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } },  // to have new IDs in the target collection
  { $out: "output-collection" }
])
```

Note *`$out` will replace the specified collection if it exists.*

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7CCzh_MThAm)

Resulting docs:

```js
[
  { "city": "Newark", "item": "2345", "size": "M", "state": "NJ", "store": "2345", "zip": "08800" },
  { "city": "Newark", "item": "2345", "size": "M", "state": "NJ", "store": "2345", "zip": "08810" },
  { "city": "New York", "item": "1234", "size": "L", "state": "NY", "store": "1234", "zip": "10000" },
  { "city": "New York", "item": "1234", "size": "L", "state": "NY", "store": "1234", "zip": "10100" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @aneroid ... this worked for me beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$setWindowFields` to compute `$rank` within the partition (i.e. the first 4 fields). Then select those with rank = 1 and `$merge` to output to another collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": {
        "state": "$state",
        "city": "$city",
        "zip": "$zip",
        "store": "$store"
      },
      "sortBy": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "rank": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "rank"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "new_collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1HNpbj6Hzvo)

Comment: Thanks ray. The solution proposed by aneroid seems to be more straightforward with fewer steps.

Comment: @Joe Glad to know that. Please help to mark aneroid's answer as accepted so that we can avoid duplicate community effort in checking the same question again.